# Finding nearest neighbors to nodes using weighted relationships

Tags: neo4j, tags, cypher, relationship

I'm having trouble finding a summation of all the weights associated with relationships.  If I have a graph and the distance between each node has a property called weight, say I wanted to find all the nodes and order by relationship weight.

## EDIT: ADDED RELATIONSHIP TO SECOND LINE

```
MATCH (album:Album)-[relationship]-(tags:Word)
WITH album, COLLECT(tags) as tags, relationship
WHERE ALL (v IN ["alpha", "bravo"] WHERE v IN EXTRACT(n in tags | n.name))
RETURN album,tags, relationship.weight as DISTANCE ORDER BY DISTANCE ASC LIMIT 15;
```

why am I getting an error with this?  When I remove relationship it works just fine, but it says 'relationship not defined' when I add this.  I want to 'ORDER BY relationship DESC LIMIT 25'.  I mainly struggling with the implementation of relationship properties so I can create a weighted graph.  Thank you in advice for advice and consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the second part of your query only knows the things you tell it in your `WITH` clause. In that clause you name the identifiers `album` and `tags`, but you don't name `relationship`. So when the time comes to return, there is no such thing as `relationship`.

Try adding `, relationship` to your `WITH` clause to bring that also into the second part of the query.

Also, please consider being consistent about capitalizing constructs of your cypher query–specifically, if you capitalize `WITH`, `WHERE`, and `ALL`, do capitalize `match` and `return`. This has no bearing on how your query is implemented, but it helps us reason about queries if we abide by the conventions.

Comment: How would I get my graph to show the 'alpha', and 'bravo' tags as well?